# retrieving images from Picasa on android

Tags: android, picasa

hello am trying to get images from an album from picasa in an android app. I tried creating an album and the album was created successfully however there is something wrong when i try to get the images in the album. Please find below my code:

```
PicasawebService myService = new PicasawebService("myApp");
myService.setUserCredentials("username", "password");
URL url = new URL ("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/myusername/albumid/myalbumid");
AlbumFeed  feed= myService.getFeed(url, AlbumFeed.class);
List<MediaContent> l;
for(PhotoEntry photo : feed.getPhotoEntries()){
l= photo.getMediaContents();
return l.get(0).getUrl().toString();
 }
```

the for loop is not being entered but when i check the size of the feed  and it shows me the correct number of images in the album. I got the code from google developers guide:(https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java#listalbums)
NB: i tried the same exact code in a desktop app and worked perfectly.
Thank you

EDIT: The problem is that the ALbumFeed is returning entries of class GPhotoEntry and not PhotoEntry. I searched online and the solution was to include the gdata-photos-meta.jar in my library which was already included...Any idea?

Comment: well am new to android development, i checked the log for exceptions and so but nothing found...note that might help: the for loop is not entered but without throwing exceptions but keeps executing the rest of the code..thx @fiddler

Answer (score 1):

google's GData doesnt work with android. You should use google Client api and they say that there is a running sample for picasa on android.